# Django - remove default localized messages (not error or help messages)

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a contact form using Django and I can't seem to figure out where this message (check image bellow) is coming from. It's a localized (in portuguese) message saying 'Please enter an email address'.
It's not the field error message (I've customized it and it appears below the field, in english). I thought it was field.help_text but I was able to change that as well and this foreign message still shows up.

Does anyone know how I can override and style this type of messages? 
Thanks in advance!

[image]

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="form">  {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form %}
        <div class="fields-container">
            <label class="label">{{ field.label }}</label>
            {{ field }}
        </div>
        <p class="server-form-errors"> {{ field.errors.as_text }} </p>
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit" id="form-button">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator   # import!

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    full_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(validators=[RegexValidator(regex=r'^[a-zA-Z\d.+*?=_@^$%&#´\{\}\|~-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9@-_]+)(\.[a-zA-Z0-9@-_]+)+\b')]
                            , error_messages={'invalid': 'Please enter a valid email address.'})
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is coming from your browser (e.g. Chrome), not from Django. It is validating the field because it has `type="email"`. I assume that the error is in Portuguese because your browser is set to Portuguese.

You can prevent the browser from validating the form by setting the [`novalidate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-novalidate) attribute.

```
<form method="post" novalidate>
    <input type="email" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Oh..so there's nothing we can do about that? Because there are other messages like that.. I've seen another one (also associated with the email field' saying something like 'insert an email with the @ symbol')

Comment: You can prevent the browser from validating by setting an attribute on the form. See my updated answer.